# How to access the elements of the nested array on firebase Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have the nested array "names" on Firestore which I am accessing using:

```
DocumentSnapshot docA = await _store.collection('nums').doc('class').get();
List<Map<String, dynamic>> peoplesNames = docA.get('names');
```

Now my challenge is to update the specific element in peoplesNames: I am trying this:
//work out the index of the name I want and serve in nameIndex.
//attached to each name is the subject List:

```
name = {
'studentname': 'John',
'subjects': ['Maths', 'English']
}
```

//work out the index of the subject I want to remove
//then try to remove it like below and that's where I am failing with the error: Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']'.

See what I am doing below:

```
_store.collection(nums).doc('class').update({'peoplesNames[nameIndex].subjects': FieldValue.arrayRemove([subject])});
```

How else can I get to remove the subject I want in this scenario without using square brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can update an element that exists in a Firestore document within an array field type using an index.

Besides that, you getting the following error:

> Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']'.

Because you're using `[` (opening square bracket) and `]` (closing square bracket) inside a path, and such characters are not allowed, hence the error.

So in such a case as yours, the single option that you have, is to read the document using `get()`, perform the update of the array in memory (using the desired index), and then write the modified document back to Firestore.